# Recombine strings based on occurrences of a pattern

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to create a method called `recombine` which takes as input 3 strings `s1`,`s2`, and `s3`. This method will recombine strings `s1` and `s2` using `s3` using the following format:

`string s1Prime = s1_Left + s3 + s2_Right;` //s1Prime is s1 after recombination

`string s2Prime  = s2_Left + s3 + s1_Right;`//s2Prime is s2 after recombination

**Recombine method code**

````
void recombine(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{
  int s1PatternIndex = s1.find(s3);
  int s2PatternIndex = s2.find(s3);

  string s1_Left = s1.substr(0,s1PatternIndex); //stores all of ```s1``` characters that are to the left of ```s3```
  string s1_Right = s1.substr(s1PatternIndex + s3.length(), s1.length()); //stores all of ```s1``` characters that are to the right of ```s3```
  
  string s2_Left = s2.substr(0,s2PatternIndex); //stores all of ```s2``` characters that are to the left of ```s3```
  string s2_Right = s2.substr(s2PatternIndex + s3.length(), s2.length()); //stores all of ```s2``` characters that are to the right of ```s3```

  string s1Prime = s1_Left + s3 + s2_Right; //```s1``` after recombination
  string s2Prime = s2_Left + s3 + s1_Right; //```s2``` after recombination

  cout << s1Prime << endl;
  cout << s2Prime << endl;
}
````

**Testing recombine method**

```
string s1 = "AGCGADA";
string s2 = "ATTGCG";
string s3 = "GC";

recombine(s1,s2,s3);

//Console output:
// s1Prime: AGCG
// s2Prime: ATTGCGADA
```

My current method only works if `s3` occurs only ONCE in s1 and s2, but I'm trying to make it do the recombination for more than 1 occurrence.

For example:

If s1 = "AGCGAGCA" and s2 = "TAGCTTGCGAT" and s3 = "GC"

In this example `s3` exists twice in `s1` and twice in `s2`, so there would be 4 different possibilities and eight different recombinations ( 4 for `s1` and 4 for `s2`)

The 4 different possibilities are:

1. Taking the 1st occurrence of `s3` in `s1` and 1st occurrence of `s3` in `s2`
2. Taking the 1st of occurrence of `s3` in `s1` and 2nd occurrence of `s3` in `s2`
3. Taking the 2nd occurrence of `s3` in `s1` and 1st occurrence of `s3` in `s2`
4. Taking the 2nd occurrence of `s3` in `s1` and 2nd occurrence of `s3` in `s2`

Please suggest how to implement this in my code.

Comment: Keep two arrays representing the position(s) of `s3` in each of `s1` and `s2`.  Then loop over all possible combinations of these using two for-loops.

Comment: @paddy I am aware of the fact that I need to keep two arrays and two-for-loop, but I'm not sure how to initialize the for loop.

Comment: Paper, pen, and boxes to represent your arrays are usually a good way to begin visualizing something.  Draw your strings into their own arrays, and draw arrows to the interesting parts of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Given a string like `AGCGAGCA`, what you can do is write a function that returns pairs of strings. Each pair is the left side, and right side of a particular occurrence of the pattern being matched, e.g.

```
  AGCGAGCA  with pattern GC
gives
 {AG, AGCA}
 {AGCGA, A}
```

Here's the function:

```
auto lefts_and_rights(std::string_view input, std::string_view pattern)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>> res;

    auto pos = std::string::npos;
    while((pos = input.find(pattern, pos + 1)) != std::string::npos)
        res.push_back(std::make_pair(input.substr(0, pos), 
                                     input.substr(pos + pattern.length())));
    
    return res;
}
```

Now you can write `recombine` conveniently like this:

```
void recombine(std::string_view s1, std::string_view s2, std::string_view s3)
{
    for (auto [left_s1, right_s1] : lefts_and_rights(s1, s3))
        for (auto [left_s2, right_s2] : lefts_and_rights(s2, s3))
        {
            std::cout << left_s1 << s3 << right_s1 << "\n";
            std::cout << left_s2 << s3 << right_s2 << "\n";
        }
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zYqao7).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm new to c++ and not quite familiar with the terms you used above, what does ```auto``` mean ?

Comment: @MightyCoder This should be covered in your textbook, or any other resource you're using.

Comment: Is there a simpler code to solve it for a beginner like me because I'm finding difficulties with understanding all those terms at once?

Comment: @MightyCoder I'm sorry the solution is difficult to understand. On the other hand, if I made the code "simpler" it would reduce the quality of the solution. You can still use the logic of the answer though. Does that part make sense? I'd be happy to edit that to make it clearer.

Comment: If you can post the simpler version here in the comments, I'd be very grateful, or send it to my email if that's possible.